# how to get all instagram fields from facebook and Instagram API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

After retiring Instagram's own API one has to use Instagram through facebook application process. Can somebody please help me in getting all information what was available using Instagram's API.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/

The above url along with **accessToken**, **clientId** and **userid** I was able to get following (not limited to) information.

```
feed.id;
feed.link;
feed.caption.created_time;
feed.caption.text;
feed.caption.from.full_name;
feed.location.name;
feed.carousel_media;                   
feed.comments.count;
feed.images.standard_resolution.url;
feed.tags;
feed.likes.count;
```

but since it is not accessible from Instagram, and https://instagram.com/developer shows

> ...The remaining Instagram Legacy API permission ("Basic Permission")
> was disabled on June 29, 2020. As of June 29, third-party apps no
> longer have access to the Legacy API. ...

the facebook is only returning following fields.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media

```
caption
id
media_type
media_url
permalink
thumbnail_url
timestamp
username
```

Can somebody please suggest me how can I get informatino about **location**, **post** **likes count**, **comments count** and **tags**.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. For further details, I will have to access through

**"Instagram Graph API"**

Instead of

**Instagram Basic Display API**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api